# Macro runs fine when in slide editor view but not slideshow view

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a macro that is supposed to run when I get to a specific slide. Now, the macro runs perfectly when Im in the slide editor view and not in the actual slideshow view. But when I am slideshow view the macro only runs half the code. I cannot figure it out for the life of me and any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
Private Sub NewMonthButton_Click()

Dim s As Shape
Dim Month As String

 'NewMonthSelection is a text box from a user form
Month = NewMonthSelection.Text

'Delete any images on the slide
For Each s In ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Shapes
    If s.Type = 13 Then s.Delete '13 is msoPicture
Next

   'Add first picture
  ActivePresentation.Slide(7).Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\" & Month & "1.PNG", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=80, Top:=120, _
   Width:=550, Height:=180).Select

   'This is where the code quits, it adds the first picture but not the second
   'unless its in the slide editor view
  ActivePresentation.Slide(7).Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\" & Month & "2.PNG", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=80, Top:=310, _
   Width:=550, Height:=180).Select

NewMonthSelection.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this in the future with similar code to mine, It was the select statement throwing it off. Here is my updated code to add the image:

With ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Shapes

```
  .AddPicture _
   FileName:="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\" & Month & "1.PNG", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Left:=80, Top:=120, Width:=550, Height:=180


  .AddPicture _
    FileName:="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\" & Month & "2.PNG", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True, Left:=80, Top:=310, Width:=550, Height:=180
End With
```